# What did Nick Fury say to Thor in Original Sin?

Tags: marvel, comics

In Original Sin #7, Nick Fury whispers something to Thor.  As you can see in [this panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntw8a.png), what Fury said was obscured, but it had a significant effect.

> It causes Thor to become unworthy of his hammer, Mjonir.

Has it been revealed anywhere what Fury said to Thor?

Comment: Interviews [with Marvel execs](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2014/08/23/original-sin-marvels-executive-editor-responds-to-igns-theories) suggest we might get the answer in the new *Thor* series, but I don't know if it's been revealed yet.

Comment: It hasn't been revealed and I wouldn't be surprised if Marvel pretend no one remembers. They're written themselves into a corner with this angle.

Comment: Speculating, he said something along the lines that Thor killed an innocent or good guy under cover

Comment: “I don't want to talk about what Nick Fury actually said to him. We will get to that at some point.” — [Jason Aaron, January 2015](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=58505)

Comment: It could just be that they're waiting for fans to give them the answer. They set up the question, they stir up all this buzz surrounding what the answer could be. Then they just cherry pick the answer they like the best and pretend like they had it planned out the entire time.

Comment: Is this considered a future work?

Comment: @alexwlchan Why not add that as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He said:

> Gorr was right

[This was revealed in *Unworthy Thor #5*.](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-mystery-that-made-thor-unworthy-has-been-revealed-1793527049)

[image: Gorr was right]

Gorr was an enemy of Asgard and Thor that claimed all Asgardians and gods were past their prime and essentially unworthy of adulation, worship, etc.

Thor realized that Gorr *was* right, that the "gods are vain", and thus he and all Asgardians were unworthy.

Comment: Wow. That was worth waiting years for

Comment: @Valorum Yeah. Wasn't expecting it to be Midlife Crisis Thor.

Comment: Worst.reveal.ever.

Answer (score 2):

**`THEORIES:`**

Thor dropping the hammer happened at the end of the series. So it has something to do with the events happened during the series. Most likely something Thor did.

> 1. Nick Fury told Thor that Kid Loki had been murdered by Old Loki, and
>      that when he took over that body Thor didn't even notice. Not
>      realising that the nice kid who wanted to beat the fate of his name
>      had been murdered and replaced has made him unworthy in his own eyes.

Kid Loki is just some kid who is the 'new' Loki, while Old Loki still existed as a disembodied spirit. When Kid Loki was tricked into killing himself by Old Loki (which he knew would happen, he just wanted to save Thor from Ragnarok), Old Loki took over that body.

Shortly after that Kid Loki grew up a bit in Young Avengers, and is currently still that age in Agent of Asgard. While he still is the same Loki that will one day commit Seige, he's trying to change his destiny, based mostly on his guilt over killing Kid Loki ("I am the crime that will not be forgiven!").

Above explanation has a connection with *Journey Into Mystery #625-632*
[image]

Unfortunately, Thor didn't take Loki's return to trickery very well and, enraged, nearly choked the kid. A tearful Loki explained that he'd done it to save Thor (who had a strange, unhealing injury; the Norns had claimed that if Loki did as they bade, Thor would be saved) and everyone else, despite how they all hated him. He then accused Thor of being just like the others, saying that it didn't matter what (Loki) did and they would hate him regardless.

Later, Thor tracked Loki down and aplogised for losing his temper, assuring him  he loved his brother — but also admitting that he didn't trust the kid.

Whatever Kid Loki did, Thor never fully trusted him. In the end, Kid Loki *died* but Thor didn't realise that. That was the reason he felt unworthy in my opinion.

> 2. Nick Fury told Thor that he caused Jane Foster's cancer.

Now we know that Jane is the new Thor. When Thor realised that he became unworth and Jane became Thor.

Answer (score -4):

I believe since the first letter is Thor I'd say that Nick Fury told Thor his real name and that he and Loki are both adopted. That's just what I think but the truth will probably be known later

Answer (score -5):

For all you've saved. For all you've sacrificed. I've seen how it ends. With all your strength... it isn't enough. YOU will bring Ragnarok to pass. By your hand... they will die.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Do you have a reference for this answer?