# Why does Odinson not attempt to regain Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

It was revealed in Original Sin #7 that after Nick Fury whispers something in Thor's ear, he loses the ability to wield Mjolnir. After this, some stuff happens and girl Thor enters the scene and boy Thor dons the name Odinson and picks up Jarnbjorn.

There has been lots of speculation on [what happened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89355/what-did-nick-fury-say-to-thor-in-original-sin) and as far as I know, we still don't have an explanation. So my question is this:

**Is there any in-universe or out-of-universe as to why Odinson does not attempt to become worthy of Mjolnir's might again?** (other than Marvel wanted to attract female readers with a female Thor)

*Note: I did not include spoiler tags for this question because it has been around for over a year now. If the community, thinks it need some, feel free to add them when applicable.

Comment: I think we have nothing more than speculations for this question. We still don't know what Fury said to Thor to cause such a reaction from him. But it also affected Thor very badly. I think this also means Thor feels so unworthy of Mjölnir, he doesn't even attempt to regain it. Again, this is just speculation.

Comment: I also think this is the most likely answer. I couldn't find it said anywhere explicitly (I don't have a ton of access to current comics) but I was wondering if Odinson said something in conversation in another book I'm not up on. Thanks for the comment!